# When do dispose of a _db connection in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dispose

I've been doing a lot of reading around garbage collecting and and using IDisposable to handle connections via entity framework. I understand that I should be disposing of resources as soon as I'm done with them but I haven't seen a lot of good examples around when exactly that call should be made and where from and want to ensure I'm handling this correctly.

Let's say I'm returning a basic inventory list from a web API call. My assumption is I should call my dispose method immediately after I get the list. Is this correct? For example's sake let's look at the below method that lives in the service layer:

```
public class ServiceLayer
{
    private InventoryContext _db = new InventoryContext();

    public List<Inventory> GetFullInventoryList()
    {
        var inventoryList = _db.Inventory.ToList();

        _db.Dispose();

        return inventoryList;
    }

    public Inventory GetInventoryRecordById(int id)
    {
        var inventoryRecord = _db.Inventory
            .Where(y => y.Id == id)
            .First();

        _db.Dispose();

        return inventoryRecord;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to dispose of resources? If not, when should it be called? If it is correct, but not the appropriate way, what is the appropriate way?

Thanks!

Comment: Googling "dbcontext dispose" finds this --> `Do I always have to call Dispose() on my DbContext objects? Nope`:  http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/

Comment: Thanks Peter, I know you don’t HAVE to but I think most people (as that author notes) think you SHOULD dispose of it.

Comment: what is _db?  Can you wrap it in a `using` statement?  Best of both worlds.

Comment: This is certainly not correct. If you want to dispose it right after query - that's fine, but then _create_ it right before query. In your example `_db` is a field which was initialized somewhere else .

Comment: Thanks PeteGO & @Evk - I added some additional code for context to show you. This is how I generally have my service layer structured. Controller calls into the service layer which has a private _db variable that is representative of the DbContext I am using

Comment: As I said - that's certainly not correct. First call to `GetFullInventoryList` will succeed but any subsequent will fail because context is already disposed. If you dispose context in some method - it should be created in the same method. If you create context in constructor of class - make that class implement `IDisposable` and dispose context there.

Comment: An alternative is to use Dependency Injection and let the container handle the lifetime of your `DbContext`, `ServiceLayer`, etc. This can use a per-request lifestyle when working in a web-request led process, for example.

Comment: @PeterB, not calling `Dispose` on `DbContext` will mean your code will rely on the implementation details of EntityFramework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options available, but all of them follow a common rule: **the owner of the context (the one who creates it) should also dispose it**.

You can:

1. Create your context in a service **method** and dispose it in the same method:

   ```
   public List<Inventory> GetFullInventoryList()
   {
       using (var _db = new InventoryContext())
       {
           return _db.Inventory.ToList();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create your context in your service **class** but then you would need to make the class IDisposable and implement the [dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern) . This is more complicated, so only use it if you need to call *multiple* service methods that each work with the database.
3. Use dependency injection to supply context to the controller. In such a case, the lifetime of the context is configured while registering it in the container, and the container will call dispose on your context (for example `Autofac` or `Windsor` do this, assuming you call dispose on the container or its life scope). You can use [PerWebRequest](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md) lifestyle for this.

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense. A lot of examples tend to lean towards dependency injection. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @serpent5, thanks a lot, after your edit the answer looks much better!

Comment: @Clouse24, generally DI is a best practice in software engineering, that improves your testability, maintainability, decreases coupling, and enables the rest of SOLID principles. Using an IoC container is a de-facto standard in modern applications. Look it up, it's really useful. Good luck!